# Coding Image gallery, PHP get WP 'Featured' img

Tags: php, wordpress

I am currently using yoxview image gallery. (www.yoxigen.com/yoxview/) But it doesn't really matter. I currently have this coded on a small splash-homepage I setup in front of a **Wordpress** install. What I am trying to do here, is allow the Image gallery via Yoxview to atomically grab & pull the set 'Featured' images assigned by Wordpress posts. I am assuming I need some **PHP** in place of the `href=""` and the `src=""` but am not sure what. Essentially, just wanting the gallery to operate dynamically and use the Featured Images set within Wordpress posts to populate as the thumbs. Could anyone help me write this? Cheers.

```
<div class="thumbnails yoxview">

    <a href="/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/broken-beer-bottle.jpg"><img src="/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/broken-beer-bottle.jpg" alt="First" title="The first image" class="thumb"/></a>

    <a href="/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/29214_116842028347050_6051723_n.jpg"><img src="/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/29214_116842028347050_6051723_n.jpg" alt="" title="The SECOND image" class="thumb" style="max-height: 100px;"/></a> 

    <a href="/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/images.jpg"><img src="/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/images.jpg" alt="" title="The Third image" class="thumb" style="max-height: 100px;"/></a>

    <a href="/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/solocups.jpg"><img src="/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/solocups.jpg" alt="" title="The Third image" class="thumb" style="max-height: 100px;"/></a>

</div>
```

**Possibly a better rephrase; how can I write in PHP 'get Wordpress featured image'?**

Comment: Do you want the single featured image? Or the attached images to the one post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the code I use to get featured image and attached images for a single post:

```
  $args = array(
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'post_mime_type' => 'image',
    'post_parent' => $post->ID,
    'post_status' => null,
    'post_type' => 'attachment',

  );

  $upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
  $upload_url = $upload_dir['baseurl'];


  // Get img data
  $attachments    = get_children( $args );
  $images = array();

  foreach($attachments as $attachment) {
    $image_attributes = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment->ID, 'thumbnail' );
    $img['thumb'] = $image_attributes[0];
    $image_attributes = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment->ID, 'large' );
    $img['large'] = $image_attributes[0];
    array_push($images,$img);
  }

  $featured_img = wp_get_attachment_url(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID));
  $featured_img_thumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'thumbnail' );
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch, @Steven. Where did you put this code, and what did you use to output it within the gallery markup? Cheers, Cam.

Comment: At the top of my single.php file. To output it, just write normal HTML and PHP `<img src="<?php echo $featured_img; ?>"/>`. If you are new to PHP and WP, then you should look at more tutorials on how to use various WP functions.